# What is the point of obvious ifs in reactjs source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found that the source code is full of comparisons `if ("production" !== "development")`.

For example (from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js, line 6240):

```
if ("production" !== "development") {
    this._checkPropTypes(
        contextTypes,
        maskedContext,
        ReactPropTypeLocations.context
    );
}
```

But why? The result of such checks is always the same.

Comment: Can you show the actual line? I mean, link to the source.

Comment: @thefourtheye I cannot find it in the sources of github repo but if you install `reactjs` via `npm` there are lots of them in `react/dist/react.js`. For example, line 6240.

Comment: Here's a direct link to react.js hosted on cdnjs.com CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js

Comment: @PeteTNT Thanks, added this link to my post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They use [browserify](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/21a9e8b6e821ac67d542dcc91b559a1a0dfc52f5/grunt/config/browserify.js#L60) with [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify).

> envify will replace your environment variable checks with ordinary
>   strings - only the variables you use will be included, so you don't
>   have to worry about, say, AWS_SECRET_KEY leaking through either. [...]
>   By running this through a good minifier (e.g. UglifyJS2), the above
>   code would be stripped out completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to enable development-only checks and logging.

If you look through the React source, you'll see `if (__DEV__)` checks, which get replaced with `if ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV)` by React's build process.

[envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) is then used to replace references to `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the source with its current value at the time the build process is run.

For the uncompressed development build of React (and when using the npm version, by default) `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `"development"`, so you get the benefit of these extra checks, such as validating props passed to component against its [`propTypes`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation), warning if [controlled components](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) are potentially read-only due to misconfiguration, warnings about lists of items without a `key` prop and all the other development-mode logging React provides for common problems such as misspelt lifecycle method  and HTML attribute prop names.

For the compressed production build, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `"production"`, so when the build is compressed with [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), these blocks of code are detected by Ugilify's dead code elimination process as code which will never get run and are completely removed from the source.

---

A nice side-effect of this is that you can take advantage of `if ("production" !== process.env.NODE_ENV)` checks to add development-only checks and logging to your own React components and libraries, since people bundling React from npm currently (with v0.12.2 the current version at the time of writing) have to deal with this as part of their build process.